# Calculation of ITD (Interaural time delay) using linear prediction - python

Tags: python, speech-processing, speech, acoustics

How is it possible to calculate the interaural time delay between two signals recorded underwater (ship sound signals)? Will linear prediction weight method be used for this?

Comment: Why not use cross correlation ?

Comment: Here signals contain noise and during that time the peak is not prominent

Comment: In general, I believe you could find many different techniques in the literature regarding Direction-of-Arrival estimation (or Time Difference of Arrival estimation). Some of the most prominent methods are the Generalised Cross Correlation (with Phase Transform being the most well known variant), Maximum Likelihood and some Bayesian Learning techniques.